# Use PowerShell to get and update string enclosed in <value> tag inside a resx file

Tags: xml, powershell, resx

Basically, I'm trying to innumerate through all strings enclosed in  tags in an .resx file, get all of them, and update some of them. Based on an answer here, I saved my .resx file as an .xml file. This is a snippet of that xml file:

```
  <data name="name1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>I/C Assembly Details</value>
    <comment>Modal Title</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="name2" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>I/C Assembly Optional Fields</value>
    <comment>Modal Title</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="name3" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Assembly Quantity Remaining</value>
    <comment>Finder</comment>
  </data>
```

And this this what I've written in PowerShell

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\Automate\test.xml)
$translatedText = "simple test"
$xml.SelectNodes("//data/value") |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.Value = $translatedText
    }
$xml.Save("C:\Automate\test.xml")
```

But it's not working with this error

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a
```

'DocumentElement' node."

Comment: The snippet you've posted is not in itself a valid XML document (it needs to have a single root element), hence the error. Try on valid XML with `$_.Value = $translatedText` changed to `$_.InnerText = $translatedText`

Comment: XMLs always needs an unique parent. Try to add <datas>your XML</datas>

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is because of your xml data missing obj tags
try adding open and closing of
`<objs></objs>`

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
 <data name="name1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>I/C Assembly Details</value>
    <comment>Modal Title</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="name2" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>I/C Assembly Optional Fields</value>
    <comment>Modal Title</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="name3" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Assembly Quantity Remaining</value>
    <comment>Finder</comment>
  </data>
</Objs>
```